# MongoDB Atlas/Realm VS Firebase

Tags: mongodb, firebase, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to create a list that shows services provided by Firebase and MongoDB Atlas. I listed some Firebase services and wrote the equivalent MongoDb service next to it. I added questionmarks to some of these services, when I could not find an equivalent service. Can anyone confirm that MongoDb does not provide a builtin solution where I added the questionmarks ?

1. Firebase Machine Laerning - MongoDB does not offer smth similiar?
2. Firstore, Realtime Database (data store) - Similiar to MongoDB’s
   data store
3. Authentication - Similiar to MongoDB’s Authentication
4. Cloud Function/Triggers - Similiar to MongoDB’s Functions/Triggers
5. Cloud Storage - Similiar to MongoDB’s GridFs
6. Google Analytics - ?
7. Remote Config - ?
8. Performance Monitoring - ?
9. Crashlytics(automatically collect, organize and analyze your app’s
   crash reports) - ?
10. Test Lab(A feature to run your application on real devices and
    sport errors early on) - ?
11. Cloud/In-App Messaging ( send users messages/push notifications) -
    ?
12. Dynamic Links - ?

Comment: What's the purpose of creating the list? Are you evaluating it for use in an application? If it's a web app then some of those services wont apply. No two product suites will ever be like-for-like but their features can be better suited to your individual requirements depending on what those are. More does not mean "better".

Comment: Yeah i totally understand that more services doesnt't mean better, but I think it might be helpful for someone to have a list of services to evaluate what the more suitable provider would be

Comment: There's a lot more to a service than just having it exist. If you were to take the centrepiece as an example (MongoDB Atlas database and Firestore database) you would find a huge difference between them from modelling to pricing (cluster size vs access patterns) to interface, to management, etc. Also the surrounding services such as Lucene-powered search offered by MongoDB but not by Firebase. The differences with one service are too many to list. It's impossible to compare one service with another unless you have a particular use case.